# How to groupby().transform() to a specific row value rather than to a function result like min()?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` that look like this:

**Input:**

```
Shop               Item  Card   Price
Butcher            A     AMEX   1.5
Butcher            A     VISA   0.9
Baker              B     AMEX   2.5
Baker              B     VISA   3.5
Candlestick maker  C     AMEX   1.5
Candlestick maker  C     VISA   1.5
```

I know that `df1.groupby(["Shop"])['Price'].transform(min)` will give me a column with `min()` of `df1.Price`

However, I would like to transform to the `Price` reached by payment with VISA, in order to compare discounts to every other value in `Card`. As you can see, this is not always `min()` and not always `max()`.

**Desired output:**

```
Shop              Item Card  Price  Price with VISA
Butcher           A    AMEX  1.5    0.9
Butcher           A    VISA  0.9    0.9
Baker             B    AMEX  2.5    3.5
Baker             B    VISA  3.5    3.5
Candlestick maker C    AMEX  1.5    1.5
Candlestick maker C    VISA  1.5    1.5
```

My current solution is based on a `for`-loop and admittedly ugly and long:

```
for shop in df1.Shop.unique().tolist():
    df_target = df1[df1.Shop == shop]
    ...
```

There must be a more efficient (i.e. one-liner) way.

**How to groupby().transform() to a specific row value rather than to a function result like min()?**

---

Edit: Note that not all `Shop` items offer `VISA` payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by filtered `DataFrame` - only `VISA` rows:

```
df1['Price'] = df1['Shop'].map(df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA'].set_index('Shop')['Price'])

print (df1)
                Shop Item  Card  Price
0            Butcher    A  AMEX    0.9
1            Butcher    A  VISA    0.9
2              Baker    B  AMEX    3.5
3              Baker    B  VISA    3.5
4  Candlestick maker    C  AMEX    1.5
5  Candlestick maker    C  VISA    1.5
```

Detail:

```
print (df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA'].set_index('Shop')['Price'])
Shop
Butcher              0.9
Baker                3.5
Candlestick maker    1.5
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

---

If get:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

it means there is more `VISA` rows per group.

Solution is aggregate `min`:

```
print (df1)
                Shop Item  Card  Price
0            Butcher    A  AMEX    1.5
1            Butcher    A  VISA    0.9 <-duplicated row
2            Butcher    A  VISA    1.9 <-duplicated row
3              Baker    B  AMEX    2.5
4              Baker    B  VISA    3.5
5  Candlestick maker    C  AMEX    1.5
6  Candlestick maker    C  VISA    1.5

df1['Price'] = df1['Shop'].map(df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA'].groupby('Shop')['Price'].min())
print (df1)
                Shop Item  Card  Price
0            Butcher    A  AMEX    0.9
1            Butcher    A  VISA    0.9
2            Butcher    A  VISA    0.9
3              Baker    B  AMEX    3.5
4              Baker    B  VISA    3.5
5  Candlestick maker    C  AMEX    1.5
6  Candlestick maker    C  VISA    1.5
```

Comment: Makes sense - in the moment, I however just get a column with NaN out from this - let me check

Comment: @sudonym - If get `NaN`s after `map` it means in some category is not `VISA` row.

Comment: you are correct - edited my question. Ideally, only those groups w/o VISA should have NaN (apologies for my lack of precision)

Comment: @sudonym - Not sure if understand, after `map` get `NaN`s for missing categories. So need change all rows to `NaN`s? E.g. if last line `Candlestick maker C    VISA  1.5    1.5` does not exist, what need in output?

Comment: no, I mean that the whole column 'df1['Price']' is 'NaN' in my setup after using the code you suggested, although 'VISA' is not missing for all groups - I have a bug somewhere, I will accept your answer as soon as I fixed it - thanks for your input

Comment: @sudonym - it is weird, `print (df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA'].set_index('Shop')['Price'])` return something?

Comment: @sudonym - If not, maybe some whitespace in `Card` column like `'VISA '` ?

Comment: I just checked. Whitespaces in "VISA" are absent. However, there are 4 of 75 groups without a "VISA" entry. I think that this leads to the whole column to be empty. If so, I need to find a way to ignore groups without "VISA".

Comment: and weirdly, print (df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA'].set_index('Shop')['Price']) returns 5 Shops only

Comment: hmm, it means for this 5 shops are not `NaNs`. It seems `df1.loc[df1['Card'] == 'VISA']` not return all `VISA rows`

Comment: The simpliest test it is add to my solution to end `print (df.dropna(subset=['Price']))`